# navigation2: crossing gates/curtain with stvl layer on

Tags: ros2, costmap, nav2

I need suggestion on the best-way to handle gate crossing with nav2.

I had nav2 deployed and working on a bot with stvl layer. I would also like to add gate  crossing feature . The gate is flexible rubber serving as a curtain. The robot has to push through without being stopped by the curtain being added into the stvl layer.

The gate location is detectable with ar-tag. I don't want to disable stvl layer, as there are usually items left around the gate and don't want to run over them.

I am considering to have two planner and controller servers (one for gate crossing and the other for regular navigation  ) each with their costmap layers.  This would allow me to set the parameters such as (obstacle height,range, max_z ) of stvl separately for gate crossing to filter out points coming from the gate.

However, I looking for a more clever way to do this. I would like to know if there is a better way to approach gate crossing or suggestion that would improves.